# How to run free command by crontab

Tags: cron, memory, proc, cache

I want to run this command:

```
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free -m
```

by cron. That way I can free my RAM and cache in an Ubuntu system.

I'm using these steps:

```
# crontab -e
2 * * * * my_user_name /usr/bin/free free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_$
```

save & exit

```
# service cron restart
```

But, when I run `free -m` nothing changes. 
For reference, it looks something like this:

```
# free -m
             total       used       free      shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7976       5064       2911           5        169       3478
-/+ buffers/cache:       1416       6560
Swap:         8112       1264       6848
```

Comment: What is `approachit` ?

Comment: Dear Sir, this my user name

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't need `service cron restart` after `crontab -e`.  `crontab -e` will automatically notify `cron` that something has changed.  If you found the crontab file, and manually went to it and edited it, you would need to do something to tell `cron` to reread the modified file (so ***don't do that*** — just use `crontab -e`).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure *why* you want to drop the caches **every hour** - that is going to kill performance.

There are a few problems with what you've done:

1. You need to edit the `crontab` of `root`, as you cannot write to `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` as a non-root user.
2. Your crontab entry is not correct. It should be:

   ```
   2 * * * * /usr/bin/free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
   ```

   The fields, in order, are: minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week, command. You don't need to restart `cron` after editing a `crontab`.

Comment: Isn't it 2 minutes after every full hour? Every 2 minutes would be `*/2`

Comment: @chaos Whoops, yes, you're right! Answer amended

Comment: Dear sir,    My system have 8 GB RAM and 128MB  Graphic card but system goes to block  screen. here i check that cpu usage are 60 -85 percent and RAM free space 130MB left. that way i drop cache for increase free space of RAM             If i am wrong please suggestion me for this

Comment: @ChanderKant The fact that the operating system is using all your RAM is a good thing - it will be caching frequently used files, etc. If you clear the caches all of that will be lost and what was previously cached will need to be loaded from disk. Rather let the operating system do what it does best - **manage your system**. See, for example [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49058/shouldnt-there-be-more-ram-free-than-this/49060#49060).

Comment: Dear Mjturnersir,  need to upgrade hardware of my system and     -/+ buffers/cache  :- used 1909      free 6067 can you help me on this topic what is the use of it

Comment: @ChanderKant What are you using your machine for? Do you have a swap file - that can help in low memory situations (and it's far better for your system to page than for you to clear caches every hour).

Comment: i have create swap partition that have created on ubuntu installation time   swap details of  root@www:~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7976       5064       2911          5        169       3478
-/+ buffers/cache:       1416       6560
Swap:         8112       1264       6848