# cannot find what has used all the memory

Tags: memory, out-of-memory

The server has about 24GB memory. By running `free -g` I find the memory is used up

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            23         23          0          0          0         18
-/+ buffers/cache:          4         19
Swap:           56          2         53
```

Then I did some research into what has used up all these memory by `top` then `M`. But it seems the memory is quite free in the `%MEM` column.

What can I do to free some memory? This is a server for calculation so it is better not to restart the computer.

Comment: What issues are you experiencing that require you to free up the cached/buffer memory?

Comment: @mtm After finding out the meaning of `free` column of `buffer/cache` row, I guess it is just OK. The server does not cache that lot before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the output of `free`.  What you posted is showing that you have 19 GB of RAM free. The 23 GB you're seeing is used by the system as cache but is still readily available for applications.  That is also why `top` shows the memory as free..

See [Linuxatemyram.com](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) for a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34795/correctly-determining-memory-usage-in-linux) for determining exact free memory.

- By default the **linux** has a *very efficient* memory management process that should be freeing any cached memory on the machine that it is being run on.
- However when it comes to **cached memory**, **linux** may at times decide that the **cached memory** is being used and is needed which can lead to memory related issues and ultimately use up the free memory. To counter it, you can force **linux** to free up any stored cached memory.

To free memory immediately, you can simply do this,

```
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
```

**EDITED**: You can also run this command as a cronjob.

As ***@mjturner*** pointed out, it not very recommended as it can cause performace bottlenecks.

Comment: What if I do not have root access on my system?

Comment: Linux creates the page and fs caches for performance reasons. I'm not sure dropping them hourly will be of much benefit. Maybe on a memory constrained machine where you don't rely on the fs much.

Comment: @Bernhard you will need root, or at least sudo root access.

Comment: Memory is managed at kernel level, you need **atleast** sudo root access. You need to give some input on what issues are affecting for further clarification as @mtm suggested.

Comment: @delta24 Well, it was not my question, I am just asking out of curiosity. :)

Comment: I was refering to @Bernhard. I was giving credit for asking it. :) Here you cannot reference 2 users in a comment. That ought to improve.

Comment: @delta24 I don't think freeing the page cache every hour is wise advice. From the [Linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt): Use of this file can cause performance problems.  Since it discards cached
objects, it may cost a significant amount of I/O and CPU to recreate the
dropped objects, especially if they were under heavy use.  Because of this,
use outside of a testing or debugging environment is not recommended.