# Tracking down Linux memory usage when not showing up in cache

Tags: linux, memory, top, memory-leaks

Before you get your pitchforks out, I am having trouble tracking down on where the memory is going into the caching system in Linux. I have seen [Linux ate my RAM!](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/), and [How to see top processes by actual memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802481/how-to-see-top-processes-by-actual-memory-usage), and [Correctly determining memory usage in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34795/correctly-determining-memory-usage-in-linux) but using those as examples, the numbers don't quite add up with the numbers I'm seeing on my system.

For this system I understand that it is probably "cached", or used by the programs, but the numbers aren't even coming close to adding up for me.

In top I see.

```
top - 09:04:09 up 19 days, 20:38,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.10, 0.11
Tasks: 160 total,   1 running, 159 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65974296k total, 43507804k used, 22466492k free,   305336k buffers
Swap:  7548924k total,        0k used,  7548924k free,  1480836k cached
```

I get it, 43GB of ram "used" isn't really true, probably most of it is probably cached. So digging into it I ran:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64428      38845      25582          0        298       1445
-/+ buffers/cache:      37101      27326
Swap:         7371          0       7371
```

So this shows that 37GB of it is indeed used and only 1445MB is cached (this is where I would have expected to see 1445 being something like 20000). The websites I linked above show that the "cached" column is usually pretty high. 
So digging further I went and did the following to check applications that were using memory.

```
    sudo smem -t
      PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS
9468
    21475 root     python /usr/bin/smem -t            0     6212     6234     6984
     2431 root     /opt/OV/lbin/perf/coda             0     7156     8060    12068
     2213 root     /opt/perf/bin/perfd                0    19056    19485    22032
    20849 root     /opt/shiny-server/ext/node/        0    77244    77321    78616
    21325 atpa     /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R --n        0  3729836  3733774  3739520
    21287 atpa     /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R --n        0  4060136  4064074  4069820
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       63 11     

                                     0  7947984  7970344  8054032
```

So two applications of R are using ~8GB of memory.

The other articles I linked above show that Linux was "reserving" the memory and keeping it in cache (e.g. free -m showed cache was high value on the "Mem:" line), whereas in my case it seemed to be actually in use but no applications actually seem to be reporting the usage of the memory and I can't seem to track down where Linux is using (caching/reserving?) the memory.

Where is this memory going? I am assuming Linux is using it, but I can't determine where it is being utilized.

`/proc/meminfo` shows

```
MemTotal:       65974296 kB
MemFree:        24191624 kB
Buffers:          305320 kB
Cached:          1480760 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          7769776 kB
Inactive:         215532 kB
Active(anon):    6199392 kB
Inactive(anon):      476 kB
Active(file):    1570384 kB
Inactive(file):   215056 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       7548924 kB
SwapFree:        7548924 kB
Dirty:               116 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       6172696 kB
Mapped:            47400 kB
Shmem:               652 kB
Slab:             255468 kB
SReclaimable:     225620 kB
SUnreclaim:        29848 kB
KernelStack:        1736 kB
PageTables:        18780 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    40536072 kB
Committed_AS:    6455352 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      247288 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359487760 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   2586624 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       10240 kB
DirectMap2M:    67098624 kB
```

Comment: Could you provide h/w setup and OS details? wondering if you have any h/w device that might be using some ram

Comment: It is just a VMWare ESXi CentOS box. Host system is a HP DL 380 has 128GB of memory 2 cpus forget which e5. There is nothing else special about the system. Do you think this could be a memory leak in an application somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found my issue...

My problem seems to have been VMware's memory ballooning system. Basically this is a way for the host system to apply memory pressure to the guest OS, consuming the guests memory allocation when other hosts start using a significant amount of memory.

http://www.vfrank.org/2013/09/18/understanding-vmware-ballooning/

If you are using VMware, run the command

```
vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon
```

This will show the amount of ballooned memory.

For me

```
#:vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon
32425 MB
```

Other sources: https://serverfault.com/questions/660080/detect-memory-ballooning-from-within-the-affected-vm

Turn off ballooned memory to validate the issue

Unballooning memory: https://serverfault.com/questions/528295/unballooning-ram-thats-been-ballooned-by-vmware