# Can't find out what hogs memory, how to troubleshoot? `free`, `top`, `htop`, `ps` didn't help

Tags: linux, memory

#### Summary

When I start my linux machine it eats about 3.7 Gigs of memory.

By the end of the day, after I close everything I used for work and then close even everything else, even stuff that was actually running in the morning, when it was using 3 Gigs, I have about 9 GiB used, excluding buffers and cache.

Looking at processes doesn't show anything suspicious. The memory is not visibly used by any of them.

```
-> free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       9.1Gi       5.4Gi        78Mi        16Gi        21Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

```
-> sudo ps --no-headers ax -o rss | awk '{rss += $1} END {print rss}'
3900356
```

Sum of all processes shows 3.7 GiB - exactly what I would expect, given how it started in the morning.

Memory is really "used" by something, I tried to claim the remaining 21 GiB, and as soon as I fill them up, system becomes unresponsive and I have to restart.

How can I find the missing memory?

#### Additional info

```
-> uname -r
5.10.16-1-default

OS: Opensuse Tumbleweed 20210215
DE: KDE Plasma 5.21
```

Comment: why you run `free` as `sudo` ?

Comment: No reason except paranoia :) I've been trying to understand what's happening for a long time, but with and without sudo result is the same. I'm going to edit the post, to avoid confusion.

Comment: have you tried `top`? i find it more usefull for such kind of inspection.

Comment: It show the percentage of memory used by each process

Comment: Read `man top`. The fields it displays are under your control.

Comment: Yes, I tried both `top` and `htop`, both show numbers that are consistent with `free` and `ps` and no trace of the owner of the "missing" memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correctly determining memory usage in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34795/correctly-determining-memory-usage-in-linux)

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's a different question with different context.